# Spring doesn't get env variable from Openshift

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deployment, openshift, fortify

I have Spring Boot Application that is automatically deployed to Openshift when I commit some change to Git.
I need to externalize the datasource config. I'm trying to use envonriment variables as solution.

This is my application.yaml

```
...

spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/DBASE
        username: ****
        password: ****

...
```

I cannot have the username and password in application.yaml because the build is scanned by Fortify, who identify  vulnerability.
Trying to use envonriment variables, I've tested firstly with env variables in Windows. I added this two envs in Windows:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
```

I've changed the application.yaml to this and worked fine.

```
...

spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/DBASE

...
```

I tried to add the same env to DeploymentConfig in Openshift but doesn't works. Spring doesn't find the envonriment variables that I created in Openshift.

This is my config in Openshift DeploymentConfigs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du8p1.png)

Some idea how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the environment variables in the configuration of `application.yaml`. For example,

```yaml
spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/DBASE
        username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
        password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be needed as Sprng Boot will interpret the environment variables. Already.